# Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire "pour quelque chose" dans ce contexte?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

> Hier au soir, en sortant de scène, un monsieur me dit « Je me félicite
>   de votre succès ». Je lui dis « mais vous n’y êtes pour rien » et puis
>   à la réflexion je me suis dit… qu’il y était tout de même **pour quelque
>   chose**, alors j’ai rectifié. Je lui ai dit : « Monsieur je vous
>   félicite de mon succès ».

Ça signifie "he was there for something" ou "he had something to do with it"?

Comment: It sounds like the thing giving you more trouble is what it means for someone to « y être » in another person's success. Without further context I might venture something like: "I congratulate myself on your success." I say to him, "But you had nothing to do with it," then on reflection I said to myself... that he did have something to do with it after all, so I corrected myself. I said to him: "Sir, I congratulate you on my success." But I'm not too confident that it doesn't have another meaning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means here "he contributed to it", "he had something to do with it" yes.

> "y être pour quelque chose"

is in fact an expression in itself which carries this meaning, so you can not really interpret the meaning of just "pour quelque chose" in this case.

Answer (score 5):

The point in that dialog is the double meaning of *je [me félicite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/f%C3%A9liciter)*<sup>*</sup>. It means either "**I'm delighted about something I contributed to**" or "**I'm delighted about something I'm not directly responsible**". The second one was meant.

However, the actor is jokingly taking the first meaning, or even literally, we would say *[au pied de la lettre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_pied_de_la_lettre)*, "**I congratulate myself on your success**" then afterwards, reverse the sentence leading to another nonsense as a punchline: "**I congratulate yourself on my success**".

*****  <sub>See B1 and B2 in the TLFi link:</sub>

<sub>1. **Se féliciter de** + subst. ou inf. Se montrer satisfait d'une initiative, d'une réussite personnelle. *Tous les jours elle se félicitait du parti qu'elle avait pris de se donner une grande passion* (Stendhal, Rouge et Noir,1830, p. 315). *On eût dit qu'elle se félicitait du bon tour qu'elle lui avait joué* (Maupass., Contes et nouv.,t. 1, Petit fût, 1884, p. 149). *Babeuf se félicite d'avoir défendu la révolution et la république (...).* *Il se félicite d'avoir sauvé la république* (Jaurès, Ét. soc.,1901, p. lxiv).

2. **Se féliciter de** + subst.; que + subj. S'estimer heureux, se réjouir d'un événement dont on n'est pas soi-même directement responsable. *Je me féliciterai toujours d'une occasion qui m'a procuré l'honneur de faire votre connaissance* (Hugo, Corresp.,1831, p. 498). *Si je me félicite du développement industriel, ce n'est pas seulement parce qu'il fournit un argument facile aux avocats de la science* (Poincaré, Valeur sc.,1905, p. 220). *Le père se félicitait que le bachot eût éloigné son cadet de Sérianne* (Aragon, Beaux quart.,1936, p. 148).</sub>

Comment: Ah! So the crux of the passage turns out to be yet another expression that didn't rear its head up at first...

Answer (score 3):

I agree that *pour quelque chose* may seem a bit abstract. In this context, for sure it means he had something to do with it: **he was involved**.

*« mais vous n’y êtes pour rien »* --> *« il y était tout de même pour quelque chose »*

Here are some alternatives:

> Je lui dis « mais vous n’y êtes pour rien » et puis à la réflexion je
> me suis dit… qu’il était tout de même **impliqué**, alors j’ai
> rectifié.
>
> Je lui dis « mais vous n’y êtes pour rien » et puis à la réflexion je
> me suis dit… qu’il y avait tout de même **participé**, alors j’ai
> rectifié.
>
> Je lui dis « mais vous n’y êtes pour rien » et puis à la réflexion je
> me suis dit… qu’il était tout de même **concerné**, alors j’ai
> rectifié.